# SharePoint Timer Job - Use Html Template from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, timer-jobs

I want to use HTML template in Timer Job.

My timer job is to send email.

I have the list of email address for To: List but I cannot access HTML template from the server.

I cannot use

```
Server.MapPath("Somepath\\test.htm")
```

Because its not a Http Request but a SpJobDefinition.

So how to access the file from the Server ?

PS: just like we use for FileUpload Control :

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("path" + fileName));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is located in the 14 hive you can use `SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath()` to get the path to your file:

```
SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("SomePath\\test.htm")
```

will return:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\SomePath\test.htm

in a default SharePoint setup.

Comment: yeah... its working for 14..... Now can I do ../. [realtive path] and go to my path to access?

Comment: No, this is not meant to be used this way. However, it's best practice to deploy your files into the 14 hive with a "wsp solution". This way you ensure that the files are available on all servers in the farm.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use Web.Config AppSetting section to read such configurations.

Here's a good example
http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/01/reading-webconfig-from-timer-job.html